# How to roam in SQL query more than one time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

A friend of mine has asked me a question which i do not know how.

The problem is he wants to use a result set of a query more than one time. Whenever he wants.

There is example tables and example output attached.

I will query two times only:

```
Select * from ornek1_ust
Select * from ornek1_alt
```

Is it possible to roam in a result set we already have with PHP to have some output like example output. I want to query database with full data for once. Then i want  to use it wherever i want whenever i want.

Example Tables:

[image: Database Table 1: ornek1_ust]

[image: Database Table 2: ornek1_alt]

Example Output:

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to "cache" the results within PHP. To fetch the data, you'd do a simple join query:

```
SELECT ornek_ust1.isim AS ust, ornek1_alt.ism AS alt
FROM ornek_ust1
JOIN ornek1_alt ON ornek_ust1.id = ornek1_alt.ust_ID
ORDER BY ornek_ust1.isim, ornek1_alt.ism
```

and within PHP, do something like:

```
$data = array();

$sql = "SELECT ...";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
   $data[$row['ust'][] = $row['alt'];
}
```

which will build an array that looks like your desired data:

```
$data = array(
    'ust data1' => array(
           0 => 'alt data 1'
           1 => 'alt data 2'
    ),
    'ust_data2' => ... etc...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to be using [mysql_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) to be able to pull out data from a resultset at will.

If you want to loop through the whole dataset and still have it available to loop through again, you can use [mysql_data_seek()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) to set the internal pointer back to the beginning.

Comment: yes, actually i want to be able to pull required data from resultset at will.

Comment: The two commands i've suggested above should serve you just fine then, you can move around your result set and use parts of it without ever having to rebuild or requery it.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the query results in an array....

```
$sql = "Select * from ornek1_ust";
$results = array();
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $results[] = $row;
}

// Use $results further on in your code
```

Comment: That will leave you with two copies of the same data.  If you're just pulling individual records from the results theres no point in looping through it and using up memory to store information you already have.